# layered costmap: How to start a local costmap?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-hydro, costmap, local-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am wondering where the resizing should be taking place.
With the global costmap and a static layer, the map gets resized when a map comes in.
But when I use the local costmap with just an obstacle, footprint and inflation layer there should be a point where the dimension should be read in.
Can you tell me where this should happen? Can't find it...

I am on ROS Hydro with the [hydro-devel navigation branch.](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146721/layered-costmap:-how-to-start-a-local-costmap?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2014-03-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not worked with this directly, but looking at the example launch and parameter files, it seems there are parameters specifying the dimenstions: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/costmap_2d/launch/example_params.yaml#L13-L16

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2014-03-31**:
Well, I found it. It's only read in over dynamic reconfigure and I don't use it!